# Apache HTTP Rewrite + Xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i'm making a pastebin clone, or atleast a personal-version of it, and for the heck of me i can't figure out why this is not working, i'm new to .htaccess and things sort of so i don't get why this isn't working. I have a main index.php file that is where you write the paste, then it saves it to a database, after that redirects you to paste.php?uid=`random unique id`, however i want it to go from that to simple /paste/`uid`. This is the currently file i have.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /paste/(.*)/$ paste.php?uid=$1
```

Comment: I think you've got your rule backwards, then. I think your rule will redirect from `/paste/uuid` to `paste.php?uid/uid`

Comment: that could be it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^paste/(.*?)/?$ paste.php?uid=$1
```

No slash at the beginning of the url, in htaccess RewriteRule.